# Why server can't push data with http?

Tags: http, protocols

Why http based on **request/response**? Why server can't push data with http to client directly and must has to be response of client request? In start of connection I know that client has to send request but why after that client must continue request/response/req/resp.  long polling, comet, Bosh and other **server pushing** method also based on req/resp method and not solve the question.

Comment: what is the question again? please rephrase

Comment: To answer your question title: because the Hypertext Transfer Protocol was designed as such.

Comment: when i design something i try to solve the problems and debug it.http also follow this but not in realtime.for realtime simple way is that server push data directly not comet not polling.what is limitation in http that server cant do this?

Comment: @jabbar When HTTP was designed, the designers considered server push to be outside the problem domain of HTTP. Remember, HTTP (and the web as a whole) looked completely different back then, with totally different usage models. For most of the history of HTTP... if you were intending to do server push, HTTP was considered *the wrong protocol for the job*.

Answer (score 0):

All your problems ok! [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) defines the WebSocket protocol. HTTP 1.1 supports bi-directional TCP-like sockets that do not require you follow the request/reply pattern. The original spec had only UTF-8 character coding support, but now with modern browsers, binary data can be sent down the wire as well. Working with WebSockets presents a new manner of framing a web application but it's growing browser support makes it a viable option for modern websites.

Node.js is the easiest way to get into using WebSocket's with the [Socket.IO](http://socket.io) library. Do check it out.

Comment: i know that we can use WebSocket for realtime but i wont to use another protocole my question is exactly that what is limitation in http that server cant push data directly?